# SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI) Throws an Exeption

Tags: android, xml, xsd, schema, ioexception

I was trying to validate and XML file over XSD in my Android App. but

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
```

line returns following error message.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Here is my code

```
  public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){
      try {
         SchemaFactory factory =
            SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
      } catch (IOException e){
         System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
         return false;
      }catch(SAXException e1){
         System.out.println("SAX Exception: "+e1.getMessage());
         return false;
      }

      return true;

   }
```

Is there any way to fix this issue in Android.